# c# debug: Process performance counter is disabled

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, debugging, process

I have an application in vs2003 in c# and it was working perfectly, I could debug without problems.

After some days, I have tried to launch again for debug some things, and now when I try to debug the application it crashes. This line is causing the exception:

```
Process[] procesos = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);
```

An the exception is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in system.dll

Additional information: Process performance counter is disabled, so the requested operation cannot be performed.
```

I do not understand why because a few days ago, in the same machine, it was working correctly and I could debug without any problems.I have not modified any line of the code, the application code is the same, no changes, so I do  not understand.

Could someone help me,please?

Comment: Have u opened visual studio in admin ?

Comment: Yes, but could you indicate me how to to this to be sure I have done correctly?

Comment: @loneshark99 In administrator is not working

Comment: Your machine is broken, the Process performance counter should never be disabled.  Ought to cause some more havoc, afaik Task Manager uses it as well.  Ask at superuser.com if you need help getting your machine back into working order.

Comment: @HansPassant and how can I repair this?

Comment: @user1624552, what about this issue? Could you enable the performance counters now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling and finding help in different sites like below:

- [Site1](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21285890/Process-performance-counter-is-disabled-exception-on-Process-GetProcessesByName.html)
- [Site2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/300956/how-to-manually-rebuild-performance-counter-library-values)
- [Site3](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8e540355-b62f-45d0-a658-b91cbe39a2db/cannot-find-process-performance-counter?forum=w8itproperf)
- [Site4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2554336/how-to-manually-rebuild-performance-counters-for-windows-server-2008-64bit-or-windows-server-2008-r2-systems)

Finally, I ended doing what is said in this [page](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2009/10/06/how-to-rebuild-performance-counters-on-windows-vistaserver20087server2008r2/). Basically what I did is executing below line of code from command prompt window (cmd) **WITH ELEVATED PERMISSIONS (RUN CMD AS ADMINISTRATOR)** under **C:\Windows\System32**:

```
LODCTR /R
```

**Important**: It is a must you open a command prompt window as Administrator. If not, above command does not work.

And performance counters are working again. You can see if they are working correctly by executing performance monitor (perfmon.exe). Once perfmon executed, if you receive some errors, it means that performance counters are corrupted, so you must execute above line of code to repair them. If not, you need to check if process counters appear under available controllers, titled as Process, and you can add some. If so, performance counters are ok.

Finally, in my case it was crashing in that line of code because Process.GetProcessesByName method uses performance counters. It seems like some .NET methods use them. So if performance counters are corrupted you will get this type of exception.